# How to format Datetime? type to "yyyy-MM-dd"

Tags: c#

I query some field from database, the Planstartdate is datetime type, and the Planstartdate can be null, I want to format the Planstartdate  to "yyyy-MM-dd"

```
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        var query = dt.AsEnumerable()
        .Select(dr =>
        new InitOverview
        {
            IID = string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr.Field<string>("IID").ToString()) ? "" : dr.Field<string>("IID"),
            ProjectName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr.Field<string>("ProjectName")) ? "" : dr.Field<string>("ProjectName"),
            TeamLead = string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr.Field<string>("TeamLead")) ? "" : dr.Field<string>("TeamLead"),
            Status = string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr.Field<string>("Status")) ? "" : dr.Field<string>("Status"),
            OverallStatus = string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr.Field<string>("OverallStatus")) ? "" : dr.Field<string>("OverallStatus"),
            Planstartdate = dr.Field<DateTime?>("Planstartdate"),
            Planenddate = dr.Field<DateTime?>("Planenddate"),
            Actualstartdate = dr.Field<DateTime?>("Actualstartdate"),
            Actualenddate = dr.Field<DateTime?>("Actualenddate")
        }
        ).ToList();
```

anybody can help to realize it?
Thanks

Comment: FYI, the expression `string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? "" : s` is partially redundant and needlessly verbose.  You could clean up your code considerably by writing `s ?? ""` or `s ?? string.Empty`, either of which is equivalent.

Comment: You could save yourself a lot of code by utilizing a micro ORM such as [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper). Manually getting database records into objects is so boring, a waste of your time. You could ditch that gross DataTable too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a nullable DateTime stored in a variable, you need to check whether it's null or not. Then you can access the underlying value and convert it to a string. [Nullable types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/) provide a boolean property `HasValue` that you should check prior to trying to work with the underlying object.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DateTime? actualStartDate = DateTime.Now;

        if(actualStartDate.HasValue)
        {
            string s = actualStartDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Console.WriteLine("value: " + s);
        }       
    }
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xFOPDF).

If you want to do this within your object initializer, it would look something like this, using a [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator):

```
new InitOverview
{
    Planstartdate = dr.Field<DateTime?>("Planstartdate").HasValue
        ? dr.Field<DateTime?>("Planstartdate").Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : "no date";
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mfXlG1).

However, I would caution you that converting it to a string at this point is probably not a good idea. In code, you should generally leave dates as dates until they actually need to be displayed to a user, so you delay it as long as possible. Only in the view layer of your application should you actually convert a date to a string. This keeps the API cleaner (no need to convert it to a date again to manipulate it) and ensures that it's simple to convert to the correct format for display to the user according to their culture settings.

Also, you're doing boring wiring up of database records to .NET objects. It's tedious and a waste of time. You should use a micro ORM such as [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) and make this much cleaner. It could be:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    return connection.Query<InitOverview>(selectStatement).AsList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mason.You really help me understand and fixed the issues

Answer (score 1):

While @mason's answer definitely works, I would like to add that since you are using DataTable, there might be the case that you are fetching dates from Database (and convert it to datatable to print in excel or vice versa), in such case 'HasValue' might not work if database contains `DBNull.Value`. Therefore, you should also check if the data you are fetching has `DBNull.Value` or not.

```
new InitOverview
{
    Planstartdate = dr["PlantStartDate"]!=DBNull.Value ? "Check Null condition mentioned in previous answer" : "no date";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Karan, I have use DateTime? type to ignore the DBNull.Value